# ios - how can I see deep link calls being made?

Tags: ios, deep-linking

Is it possible to see all deep link calls that my app does? I'm using a framework that is deep linking, and I'd like to know more about what's happening. Is it possible to see the calls that are made? I can see the deep links to my apps from the AppDelegate entry point, but how can I see the calls from my app to other apps?

Comment: Can you show what framework are you using for deep linking

Comment: I wish I could :)

Comment: Can you share the name or the link from whr u downloaded the framework